# Review the document

Tags: spring-boot, docusignapi, hellosign-api, e-signature

I want to build a system where a document is to be signed/reviewed by the user. It may be the case that user takes 10 days to sign/review the document or even in minutes things are done.

By review : user shall review the document, but no need to sign it. Only accept/decline button or any alternative should be there so that we are aware of the outcome of the document.

By Sign : user shall go through the document and should sign it.

How to do review kind of flow?

Answer (score 0):

The DocuSign system supports many [different types of recipients](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/recipients/).
The most common one is called a Signer and that's the second one you mention.
What you call "Review" has a couple of different names in DocuSign. In the web app it's called "Need to View" which is exactly what you describe, you must review the document, but there's no need to sign.

Using the eSignature API, this type of recipient is called "Certified Delivery" as DocuSign certified that the document was not only delivered, but opened and viewed (We can't ensure the person actually read it and comprehend it).

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/recipients/

Answer (score 0):

The HelloSign API has a few options for you depending on your use case and if you would like to use templates or not. For instance:

When your site user needs to send a signature request based on a template, you will need to create an embedded signature request draft. This draft can be opened in an embedded iFrame to allow the user to preview the request prior to sending. Creating the signature request draft for previewing is also a perfect opportunity to populate any pre-defined merge fields that might have been added by the user during the template creation process.

The embedded iFrame will be displayed and the user will be given an opportunity to preview and make edits to the signature request prior to sending. Any custom_fields parameters supplied to the draft creation API request will be added to the document as well and these fields can also be edited and moved by the user. The user can then send the signature request by clicking "Continue" (or "Send" if the subject and message for the request have already been set).

If the user that is reviewing also needs to sign the request, they can make sure they are a signer listed to complete the request.

https://app.hellosign.com/api/embeddedTemplatesWalkthrough#EmbeddedTemplatesPreviewingASignatureRequest